# jsonb: como buscar o valor da mesma chave de todos os objetos em um array?

Tags: json, postgresql

Tenho uma coluna de tipo `jsonb` que guarda objetos em um array.

Eu consigo buscar a chave `template` de todos os objetos de índice `0` assim:

```
psql=# select data->'components'->0->'template' as template from page;
```

que retorna:

```
template             
-------------------------------------
 "nome-do-template"
 //etc
(100 rows)
```

Como posso fazer pra buscar a chave `template` de todos os objetos ao mesmo tempo, sem especificar o índice?

**EDIT:** exemplo de array armazenado:

```
[
  {
    "type": "feed",
    "template": "_vertical-content",
  },
  {
    "type": "feature",
    "template": "_single-content",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

A função `jsonb_array_elements` expande um array para um conjunto de valores json, dessa maneira só é necessário filtrar essas tuplas retornando o conteúdo da chave `template`.

Caso seja necessário retornar os resultados em uma só linha basta utilizar alguma função de agregação como o `array_agg`.

```
with d(dados) as (
    select 
        jsonb_array_elements(data#>'{components}') 
    from teste
)
select dados->>'template'
from d;
```

Resultado:

```
    template      
-------------------
_vertical-content
_single-content
(2 registros)
```

Obs: Realizei o teste considerando que o array json corresponde a key `components`.